# Element of an object as an argument to a function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use an object element in the JS as a parameter in a function?

Here is an example, it does not work:

```
  var someFunc = function(a, b) {

  var items = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }

  return items.a;
};
```

Comment: You mean `items[a]`? Also, the function params are different from the ones in `items`.

Comment: You're currently setting `items.a` to `1` and returning `items.a`, hence always `1`. `alert(someFunc())` will alert `1` regardless of what you pass to the function. The parameter `a` is never used. Did you intend to set `items.a` to the value of this parameter? In that case, use `items = { a: a, b: b }; return items.a;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call the function in a way that a has value 'a', but then you are using wrong notation to get value from items object. `items.a` means you are trying to access key named 'a' from items which will always return 1. use items[a] to access key stored in variable a.

```
 var someFunc = function(a, b) {

      var items = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
      }

      return items[a];
    };
someFunc('a','b');
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you could use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
var someFunc = function(a, b) {
        return { [a]: 1, [b]: 2 };
    };

console.log(someFunc('foo', 'bar'));
```

If not available, you could use a simple assignment with bracket notation as a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```js
var someFunc = function(a, b) {
        var temp = {};
        temp[a] = 1;
        temp[b] = 2;
        return temp;
    };

console.log(someFunc('foo', 'bar'));
```